# "Caching" multiple database table

Tags: java, database, caching

My program is connected with two different databases. "User" table is exist in both database.
I want to create a single user cache of both table.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in Java create a "[Materialized View](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm%20Materliazed%20View)" or  "[View](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm)" IN DB itselffrom both the tables and then access these VIEW or materialized views in Java. You can access the other DB via DB link.

However if you want to have a USER cache itself then use a hashset to weed out the duplicates.